# SQLAlchemy: Closing Question Due To User Error

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

### Update

---

User error :/ I found a sneaky rollback() call that was inadvertently being called.... Thanks to those that helped

---

I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this one out. I'm using python 3.8.3 flask 1.1.2, sqlalchemy 1.13.17, flask-sqlalchemy 2.4.3, psycopg2-binary 2.8.5.

Here is the relevant code where I create the object

```
        logger.info("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        logger.info(f"1. {Enrollment.query.all() = }")

        enrollment = program.create_enrollment(student, payment_option)
        logger.info(f"2. {Enrollment.query.all() = }")
        logger.info(f"3. {Enrollment.query.all() = }")
```

---

```
def create_enrollment(self, student, payment_opt):
    validate_enrollment(self, student)
    enrollment = Enrollment(self, student, payment_opt)
    return enrollment
```

---

## enrollment.py

```
def __init__(self, program, student, payment_option=None):
    self.program = program
    self.student = student
    self.cost = program.cost
    self.payment_option = payment_option
    super().__init__()
    db.session.add(self)
    # autoflush is turned off
    db.session.flush()
```

I've added the 3 logging calls to illustrate the problem (first snippet).

1. The first query returns 1 Enrollment object which already exists
2. The second query is called after the new Enrollment object is created and correctly shows both objects
3. The third query only shows the first object again...

Log output

```
06/24/20 00:06:18 - INFO - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06/24/20 00:06:18 - INFO - 1. Enrollment.query.all() = [<Enrollment 32f1dc97-9323-44b5-830a-27be1d8dbc9b>]
06/24/20 00:06:18 - INFO - 2. Enrollment.query.all() = [<Enrollment f7db2a39-fc4c-4282-8c0f-dd4f92918077>, <Enrollment 32f1dc97-9323-44b5-830a-27be1d8dbc9b>]
06/24/20 00:06:18 - INFO - 2. Enrollment.query.all() = [<Enrollment 32f1dc97-9323-44b5-830a-27be1d8dbc9b>]
```

This causes downstream errors when I query for the enrollment ID and nothing gets returned. Why would repeated calls to `query` produce different returns?

---

If I change the logging calls to:

```
        enrollment = program.create_enrollment(student, payment_option)
        logger.info(f"{enrollment = }")
        logger.info(f"{enrollment = }")
```

I can see that the second time I log the enrollment it's switched its state back to transient:

```
06/24/20 01:52:36 - INFO - enrollment = <Enrollment 2ac370bb-bf55-4bba-a126-c44417fe0055>
06/24/20 01:52:36 - INFO - enrollment = <Enrollment (transient 139766640676096)>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

---

### Edit

per the comment from @above_c_level I moved the db.session.add() and flush calls outside of the **init** method. I also added additional logging calls

```
        from sqlalchemy import inspect
        logger.info("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

        enrollment = program.create_enrollment(student, payment_option)
        db.session.add(enrollment)
        db.session.flush()
        insp = inspect(enrollment)
        logger.info(f"{insp.transient = }")
        logger.info(f"{insp.pending = }")
        logger.info(f"{insp.session = }")
        logger.info(f"{db.session = }")
        logger.info(f"{enrollment = }")
```

Which produces:

```
06/24/20 12:27:59 - INFO - insp.transient = False
06/24/20 12:27:59 - INFO - insp.pending = False
06/24/20 12:27:59 - INFO - insp.session = None
06/24/20 12:27:59 - INFO - db.session = <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session object at 0x7f6a70b95370>
06/24/20 12:27:59 - INFO - enrollment = <Enrollment (transient 140095099150832)>
```

The object isn't being added to the current session..

Comment: You use `db.session.flush()` this will keep changes in the current session and will be visible if you run `query.all()` in the current session. Do you also have a commit statement i.e. `db.session.commit()`?

Comment: @PGHE I call commit() at the end of the entire transaction if no errors occur before- What I'm most confused about is that the object goes from pending back to transient in the same session just by referencing it

Comment: My hunch is that you should not use session.add() and session.flush() in the init of Enrollment. Can you refactor these calls in a new method of Enrollment?

Comment: @above_c_level I updated the question with your suggestion